# How do you say and spell “Тоска”

Tags: произношение, правописание, существительные, орфография

I am very curious about the Russian word “Toska.” The word that is difficult to translate in English and means loosely: melancholy, longing, boredom, spiritual anguish. How is this word written and accented in Russian using Russian letters? What does it look like? Also, how do you pronounce it? Thanks.

Comment: Тоска is pronounced as "таска" with the stress on last syllable.

Comment: Thank you so much... just a quick follow-up.. In English you would not call it "toska?" with an S? What would it look like in Russian using cyrillic? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "Toska" in cyrillic letters is "тоска".

Comment: I mean how it's pronounced if you are speaking English and saying the word. You wouldn't say "To-s-k-a" you would say "t-a-ck-a" with no soft "s" sound correct?

Comment: Google Translate reads aloud [tuskaah] similar to how "тоска" is pronounced in Russian: https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/tuskaah Just click on "speaker" icon at the lower right corner of the left text box.

Comment: Have you heard about Forvo? Answers questions like these really quickly. http://www.forvo.com/word/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0/#ru

Comment: Tosca ("Тоска" with the stress on first syllable) is an opera in three acts by Giacomo Puccini.

Answer (score 6):

`Тоска` - [tʌˈska]

> стеснение духа, томление души, мучительная грусть; душевная тревога,  беспокойство, боязнь, скука, горе, печаль, нойка сердца, скорбь.

further reading a definition from the dictionary by Dal you can find [here](http://dal.sci-lib.com/word040036.html)

and good web formatted description and further meanings you can find [here](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> 1. сильное душевное томление, душевная тревога в соединении с грустью и скукой, тягостное уныние
>
> ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hear the exact pronunciation here for example:

[http://slovari.yandex.ru/тоска/](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqJKMv09mww&t=25m30s

Опять **тоска**, опять любовь!

Comment: or by using https://translate.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

> How is this word written and accented in Russian using Russian letters?

**Тоска**.

It accented (big character means accent):
**taskA**.
Like "task"+"A". Where A=[a]

Comment: It seems like using latin letters to show the pronunciation is not a best idea. Task, for instance, sounds like "тэск". This is misguiding.

Comment: May be you are right. Wiktionary gives two pronunciatons -- (Received Pronunciation) IPA(key): /tɑːsk/ ;
(US) IPA(key): /tæsk/ .

So Rus. word has pronunc. [tɐsˈka] (from Wiktionary) or simply [tasˈka].